# When I build an Eloquent relationship it makes problem here I show my code I use tinker to see relation but it doesn't build

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I build an Eloquent relationship it makes problem here I show my code I use tinker to see relation but it doesn't build

**pass.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class pass extends Model
{
    public function salman()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(salman::class);
    }
}
```

**salman.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class salman extends Model
{
    public function passport()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(pass::class);
    }
}
```

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'passes.salman_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `passes` where `passes`.`salman_id` = 1 and `passes`.`salman_id` is not null limit 1)

Previous exceptions

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'passes.salman_id' in 'where clause' (42S22)

Comment: Please can you show the table structures or migration files for the models? Can you also show the query that is causing the error?

Comment: can you add the "....create_pass**_table.php" migration file as well?

Comment: Schema::create('passes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('number')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('na_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: Schema::create('salmen', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: Please paste your $fillable also in model code

Answer (score 0):

In your database table `passes` you must have a column named `salman_id`.

So in your migration file add:

```
$table->unsignedInteger("salman_id");
```

Comment: The value should be unsigned as it is a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because Laravel looks for a `salman_id`(for table salman) by default.

If yes, then you can specify your custom primary key like below.

**Change this line:**

```
    return $this->belongsTo(salman::class);
```

**To:**

```
    return $this->belongsTo(salman::class, 'id', 'id');
```